# Unmanaged C++ regfree COM application: problems when launching from IDE with parent directory in path (VS2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, com, regfreecom

I have an application A and a DLL B, both unmanaged C++ built in VS2010. DLL B is a COM server. A uses both implicit C++ linkage to B for some methods and classes but it is also accessing coclasses implemented in B via COM. This all works fine when using registered COM, but when A is using B via registration free COM, a weird problem is occuring.

When I start A from within the IDE (either F5 or Ctrl+F5), then my application crashes when trying to cocreate a coclass implemented in B. I also noticed that when I try to debug this the Visual Studio Debugger sometimes simply ignores my commands to step into methods. The source code and what is actually executing seem to be somehow out of sync.

I then eventually found the cause of the problem: In application A's Debugging settings Command is set to $(TargetPath). $(TargetPath) in turn uses the project's output directory which was set to "$(ProjectDir)..\bin\". Changing the output directory to an absolute path that does not contain the ".." parent directory syntax, solved the problem, even though the directory pointed to was exactly the same.

Can anyone explain what is going on there? I have a vague idea that it has something to do with the fact that my application both loads B.dll at startup via implicit C++ linkage and also lists it as a dependent assembly in its manifest for registration free COM. Could this lead to B dll somehow being loaded twice? And why does this only happen when starting A from within the IDE? When launching A from the command line, using ".." in thee path works fine.

Comment: So I used Process Monitor to dig a bit deeper into what is going on here and made 2 discoveries:

1) When starting from the cmmand line, any ".." in the process path are aparently resolved by cmd.exe before the process is launched, whereas when starting from within Visual Studio the ".." shows up in process monitor, this explains why the error occcurs only from within the IDE


2) In those cases where the application crashes (proccess path with ".." started from IDE) B.dll is shown to be loaded multiple times by Process monitor, always from the same location. But how can this happen?